# uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

[image]

Error:Execution failed for task ':baseGameUtils:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4] C:\Users\nekos.android\build-cache\ac3e2c727e192cdc9e7fe0403f8315232b0e8024\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads.impl" to force usage

Comment: Recent versions of Play Services and the Android Support Library no longer support older Android devices. Their `minSdkVersion` is 14. Yours is 9. You need to either raise your `minSdkVersion` to 14 or use older versions of libraries like `play-services-ads`.

Comment: Specifically, `10.0.1` is the last version of the support library to support Gingerbread.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Services don't support Android APi 2.3x (Gingerbread) starting from Google Play Services 10.2, Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_2017_-_version_102):

> Google Play services 10.2.x is the first release that no longer
>   includes full support for Android version 2.3.x (Gingerbread). Apps
>   developed using SDK release 10.2.x and later require a minimum Android
>   API level of 14 and cannot be installed on devices running an API
>   level below 14.

If you happen to use support library, please be noted that version 26 also need minimum api level 14.